# When linking a c# asp.net web application with a C++ dll is the dll code running on the server or the client?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, dll

What I would like to do is write to a log file from the C++ dll but it doesn't seem to work.  I can write to a server side log file from c# code behind so I know it is possible to write to  a file on the server.  I can pass data to and from the C++ dll from the web application so I know the dll is linked correctly.  The dll will write to a file when linked to a console application so I know the file I/O code works.  It won't write to a file when linked to the web application.  So my thinking is the dll is running on the client?  All my testing is done locally so sometimes it is hard to figure out what is client and what is server.

If it is running on the client is it possible to link to a dll and have it run on the server?

Comment: The DLL is on the server and is run there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# code, and all functions called by C# code, always runs only on the server.

The only way to run code on the client is to send it over the network and ask the browser to run it.
No sane browser will run C++ for you.

Comment: Ok, so that is what I want since I would like to write to a log file on the server from the c++ dll.

Comment: Plus One for the phrase "No sane browser..."